# CSS width of page higher than 100%

Tags: html, css, ios, width, viewport

I am currently working on a small SCSS framework which can be viewed here: **http://framework.pixxelone.de/**
However, I have some issues with the max-width of the header on all devices which causes problems. If I open it on iPhone, I can scroll to the right which should not be possible. On iPad Viewport (simulated in Chrome, I don't have one) the viewport of the header is also not correct. The menu is cut off and also some part of the main content is cut off on the right side.

Without device-specific viewport in Chrome, you can also scroll to the right (although it's shown correctly in the viewport). I am pretty sure that it has to do something with the header or the elements in the header (especially main menu) but I can't figure out what to do to solve this.

I found some similar posts like this which were solved by adding box-sizing: border-box; but this did not help here. I also can't find any elements that are bigger than the width it should be.

[image: iPhone viewport]

[image: iPad Viewport]

```js
"use strict";

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    let hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu");

    hamburgerMenu.addEventListener("click", function () { // Event bei Klick hinzufügen
        hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle("is-active"); // is active ändert den Hamburger zu einem X

        let navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
        navigation.classList.toggle("hamburger-toggle-nav-display-block"); // bei Klick Klasse hinzufügen und damit anzeigen, bei erneuten Klick Klasse entfernen und damit ausblenden
        hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle("z-index-9999");

    }, false);

}, false);
```

```css
// VARIABLES
// Navigation top
$navigation-top-background: $color-initial;
$navigation-top-border-bottom: 0.4rem solid $color-primary;

$navigation-top-a-color: $standard-font-color;
$navigation-top-a-color-hover: $color-primary;
$navigation-top-a-color-active: $color-primary;
$navigation-top-a-transition: $transition-time;

$navigation-top-nav-padding: 2.0rem;

// Variablen zur Berechnung der Höhe des Headers, um dann automatisch den margin für den main content zu bekommen
$logo-height: 4.0rem;
$logo-width: 20.0rem;
$header-height: 8.0rem;

// mobile nav Ausklappmenu
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-padding: 2.0rem;
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-background: $color-initial;
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-right: 2.0rem;
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-top: 6.0rem;
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-width: 80%;
$navigation-top-ausklappmenu-max-width: 40rem;


// Navigation top Hamburger
$hamburger-padding-x           : 15px !default;
$hamburger-padding-y           : 15px !default;
$hamburger-layer-width         : 40px !default;
$hamburger-layer-height        : 4px !default;
$hamburger-layer-spacing       : 6px !default;
$hamburger-layer-border-radius : 4px !default;

// Colours
$hamburger-layer-color         : black !default;

$hamburger-hover-layer-color   : $color-primary !default;
$hamburger-hover-opacity       : 1.0 !default;

$hamburger-active-layer-color  : $color-primary !default;
$hamburger-active-hover-opacity: 1.0 !default;
$hamburger-active-label-color  : $color-primary !default;


$hamburger-label-color         : black !default;
$hamburger-label-color-hover   : black !default;
$hamburger-label-color-active  : $color-primary !default;



// GENERAL NAVIGATION TOP
header {
 background: $navigation-top-background;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border-bottom: $navigation-top-border-bottom;
 z-index: 100;

 #logo {
  margin-left: $grid-container-padding-left-right-smartphone;
  margin-top: ($header-height - $logo-height) / 2;
  margin-bottom: ($header-height - $logo-height) / 2;
  float: left;
  width: $logo-width;
  height: $logo-height;
  background: url() no-repeat center; // link in html
  background-size: contain;
  display: block;
 }

 nav {
  display: none; // mobile
  float: right;
  padding: 0;

  &:hover ul {
   display: block;
  }

  ul,
  &:active ul {
   position: absolute;
   padding: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-padding;
   background: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-background;
   box-shadow: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-box-shadow;
   right: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-right;
   top: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-top;
   width: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-width;
   max-width: $navigation-top-ausklappmenu-max-width;
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
  }

  ul li {
   display: inline-block !important;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 1.0rem 0;
   margin: 0;

   & a {
    color: $navigation-top-a-color;

    &:hover {
     color: $navigation-top-a-color-hover;
     transition: $navigation-top-a-transition;
    }

    &:active {
     color: $navigation-top-a-color-active;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}


@media all and (min-width: $tablets-landscape-and-bigger) {
 header {
  position: fixed;

  #logo {
   margin-left: $grid-container-padding-left-right-desktop;
  }

  nav {
   ul,
   &:active ul {
    display: inline-block;
    //height: $header-height;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0 solid $color-initial;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); // remove shadow
   }

   ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: $header-height;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 1.0rem;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
   }
  }
 }
}





// HAMBURGER ICON
/*!
 * Hamburgers
 * @description Tasty CSS-animated hamburgers
 * @author Jonathan Suh @jonsuh
 * @site https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers
 * @link https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers
 */


// Types
// ==================================================
$hamburger-types: (
  collapse
) !default;

// Base Hamburger
// ==================================================

button#hamburger-menu:hover, button#hamburger-menu:focus {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  color: black;
}


.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  right: $grid-container-padding-left-right-smartphone;
  top: (($header-height - 3.8rem) / 2) ; // 3.8rem = height vom kompletten hamburger
  // padding: $hamburger-padding-y $hamburger-padding-x;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;

  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;

  // Normalize (<button>)
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;

  .hamburger-label {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: $hamburger-label-color;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    opacity: $hamburger-hover-opacity;

    .hamburger-inner,
    .hamburger-inner::before,
    .hamburger-inner::after {
      background-color: $hamburger-hover-layer-color;
    }

    .hamburger-label {
        color: $color-primary;
    }
  }

  &.is-active {
    &:hover {
      opacity: $hamburger-active-hover-opacity;
    }

    .hamburger-inner,
    .hamburger-inner::before,
    .hamburger-inner::after {
      background-color: $hamburger-active-layer-color;
    }

    .hamburger-label {
      color: $hamburger-label-color-active;
    }
  }
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: $hamburger-layer-width;
  height: $hamburger-layer-height * 3 + $hamburger-layer-spacing * 2;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: $hamburger-layer-height / -2;

  &,
  &::before,
  &::after {
    width: $hamburger-layer-width;
    height: $hamburger-layer-height;
    background-color: $hamburger-layer-color;
    border-radius: $hamburger-layer-border-radius;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
  }

  &::before {
    top: ($hamburger-layer-spacing + $hamburger-layer-height) * -1;
  }

  &::after {
    bottom: ($hamburger-layer-spacing + $hamburger-layer-height) * -1;
  }
}


.hamburger-toggle-nav-display-none {
  display: none;
}
.hamburger-toggle-nav-display-block {
  display: block !important;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
  width: 100%;

  ul {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.z-index-9999 {
  z-index: 9999;
}



@media all and (min-width: $tablets-landscape-and-bigger) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }

  #navigation {
    display: block; // nav wieder anzeigen
  }
}


// Collapse Animation
// ==================================================
@if index($hamburger-types, collapse) {
  .hamburger--collapse {
    .hamburger-inner {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      transition-duration: 0.13s;
      transition-delay: 0.13s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);

      &::after {
        top: ($hamburger-layer-spacing * 2 + $hamburger-layer-height * 2) * -1;
        transition: top 0.2s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1),
                    opacity 0.1s linear;
      }

      &::before {
        transition: top 0.12s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1),
                    transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
      }
    }

    &.is-active {
      .hamburger-inner {
        transform: translate3d(0, ($hamburger-layer-spacing + $hamburger-layer-height) * -1, 0) rotate(-45deg);
        transition-delay: 0.22s;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);

        &::after {
          top: 0;
          opacity: 0;
          transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333),
                      opacity 0.1s 0.22s linear;
        }

        &::before {
          top: 0;
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
          transition: top 0.1s 0.16s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333),
                      transform 0.13s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
   <a href="#" id="logo" style="background: url(img/testlogo.svg) no-repeat center;"></a>
   <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-user"></i> About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Work</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-rss"></i> Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
   <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button" id="hamburger-menu">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
     <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="hamburger-label">Menü</span>
   </button>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with `.row` if you check in the CSS the width is set as `width: calc(100% + 2.0rem);`.

The horizontal scrollbar is shown because the `<section class="tile-container">` is set to full width, therefore the row goes further.

For tablet view the problem seems to be with the `<canvas>` in the final section of the page. Its width is 100% which is what causes the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was in the media query:

`@media (min-width: 64em)
header {
    /* position: fixed; */
}`

When I unchecked this, the header took 100% of the screen and didn't go outside of the viewport.